# How to access session variable in global.asa file

Tags: asp-classic, jscript

I am handling a classic asp code which is already developed.
We are initializing session variable on login page and accessing it in session_onstart in `global.asa` file to access data from the database.

I am getting an session value as `undefined`.

Sorry for this stupid question but is there any way to tackle this situation?

Comment: Global.asa is the very, very first page that will be executed when an ASP page on your site is called for the first time. That's where sessions are born... so if you try accessing a session variable in session_onstart that has not been created in that same function in the previous lines of code, you will always get an undefined (because Global.asa executes BEFORE your loginpage.asp)

Comment: Thank you very much. I have corrected the code now and written code in global.asa file into different file.